# Async Function working in Express but not NestJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I initially created a little express server to run a report and file write function.

```
var ssrs = require('mssql-ssrs');
var fs = require('fs');

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    reportCreation();
    res.send('File Created');
})

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    reportCreation();
    res.json({'File Created': true});
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Report Api listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

The function reportCreation() is an async function which gets a report from a SSRS. This works fine

```
async function reportCreation() {
var serverUrl = 'http://reportServerName/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx';

ssrs.setServerUrl(serverUrl);

var reportPath = '/ApplicationPortalReports/TestReportNew';
var fileType = 'word';
var parameters = { ApplicationId: 3, TrainingCardId: 267, PortalPersonId: 52 }

var auth = {
    username: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'PASSWORD',
    domain: 'dmz'
};

try {
    var report = await ssrs.reportExecution.getReportByUrl(reportPath, fileType, parameters, auth)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
console.log(report);
try {
    fs.writeFile('ReportApiTest.doc', report, (err) => {
        if (!err) console.log('Data written');
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

}
```

I have been working a lot with NestJs recently and wanted to use the same function but within a NestJs service.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  async  getReport(): Promise<string> {
   
    const serverUrl = 'http://reportServerName/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx';

    ssrs.setServerUrl(serverUrl);
    const reportPath = '/ApplicationPortalReports/TestReportNew';
    const fileType = 'word';
    // var parameters = {appId: 3, ReportInstanceId: 1 }
    const parameters = {ApplicationId: 3, TrainingCardId: 267, PortalPersonId: 52 };

    const auth = {
      username: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
      domain: 'dmz'
    };

    try {
       var report = await ssrs.reportExecution.getReportByUrl(reportPath, fileType, parameters, auth)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      console.log(report);

      // excel = xlsx
      // word = doc
      // pdf = pdf
    try {
      fs.writeFile('ReportApiTest.doc', report,  (err) => {
          if (!err) { console.log('Data written'); 
        return 'File Written Succesfully'}
        });
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return 'File Write Error'
      }
      }
  }
```

As you can see the files are almost identical, but when I run it through NestJs I get an error which looks like a problem with the line

```
var report = await ssrs.reportExecution.getReportByUrl(reportPath, fileType, parameters, auth)
```

not **awaiting**. Why does this work with Express and not NestJS? Below is the error from NestJs

```
buffer.js:219
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined
    at Function.from (buffer.js:219:9)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:179:17)
    at Object.createType3Message (C:\Projects\SSRS-report-api\ssrs-report-api\node_modules\httpntlm\ntlm.js:172:19)
    at sendType3Message (C:\Projects\SSRS-report-api\ssrs-report-api\node_modules\httpntlm\httpntlm.js:77:23)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Projects\SSRS-report-api\ssrs-report-api\node_modules\httpntlm\httpntlm.js:101:4)
```

within the mssql-ssrs node package the getReportByURL looks like this

```
async function getReportByUrl(reportPath, fileType, params, auth) {
    try {
        var config = {
            binary: true, // very important
            username: auth.userName,
            password: auth.password,
            workstation: auth.workstation,
            domain: auth.domain,
            url: soap.getServerUrl()
                + "?" + (testReportPath(reportPath).replace(/\s/g, '+'))
                + "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=" + reportFormat(fileType)
                + formatParamsToUrl(params)
        };
    } catch (err) { report.errorHandler(err) }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        config.url = encodeURI(config.url);
        httpntlm.post(config, function (err, res) {
            if (res.statusCode === 500) { reject(res) }
            if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) { reject(err) }
            else { resolve(res.body) }
        })
    })
```

}

Here is the app.controller.ts

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
     constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): Promise<string> {
    return this.appService.getReport();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is implementation of getReportByUrl method?

Comment: Why do you have return statements in in `writeFiles` and not in express code ?

Comment: From where do you call this ? Can you post the controller ? or the place you call this method.

Comment: The error clearly says ```Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined``` . So you should first compare the config object value from express and nestjs. It seems like there is a diff in the value.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I will post the controller now. @Dilshan because this is called by a controller function that needs a string returned (I copied the default one, so they might not actually be needed) I don't think that is making a difference. iAviator I will console.log the config object and see.

Comment: @iAviator console logging the config file shows that I did indeed edit the node_module reportExecution file from userName to username and had not done so in the NestJS version. Silly me! I have it working now thanks to your advice. I'm not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: @Bwizard can u upvote the comment that helped you

Comment: Your use of `try..catch` is completely improper. If you want to log the error, that's fine, but then you have to `throw` or at minimum `return` or remove the `try..catch`. To top it off, a really sneaky and insidious use of `var` is what allows you to even get away with it. Shame on you for doing this to yourself!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer for the question. But after I see your code, I can see an error you will face in future if `await ssrs.reportExecution.getReportByUrl(reportPath, fileType, parameters, auth)` failed. Actually you see above error because of this.

The way you used the try catch is really bad.

Here's the way I code it.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  async  getReport(): Promise<string> {
    const serverUrl = 'http://reportServerName/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx';

    ssrs.setServerUrl(serverUrl);
    const reportPath = '/ApplicationPortalReports/TestReportNew';
    const fileType = 'word';
    // var parameters = {appId: 3, ReportInstanceId: 1 }
    const parameters = {ApplicationId: 3, TrainingCardId: 267, PortalPersonId: 52 };

    const auth = {
      username: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
      domain: 'dmz'
    };

    const report = await ssrs.reportExecution.getReportByUrl(reportPath, fileType, parameters, auth)

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile('ReportApiTest.doc', report, , function(err) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve("File Created");
        });
    });
  }
```

And in my controller

```
@POST
async writeFile() {
    try {
        const res = await this.appService.getReport();
        return res;
    } catch(err) {
        // handle your error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had fudged the code in the node_module changing the userName variable to username and had not done the same in the NestJS version. I forgot I had done that so now it is working.

Comment: Just delete the question. This does not answer it as it was asked.